# Correct view is not rendered - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, file-upload, view

I'm trying to create a dropzone where users can drop multiple files at once. The problem is that it only renders the dropzone when I reload the webpage, and not when I open it for the first time. I mean, when I click to open the view that takes care of the uploads, I just get the **browse** and **upload** buttons that you'll see in my code, but when I reload the page I get the dropzone box. I can not see what I missing here. The code I wrote was:

**_new.html.erb**

```
<center>
<% @upload = Upload.new %>
<%= form_for @upload , html: { :multipart => true, class: "dropzone"} do |u| %>
    <div class="fallback">
        <%= u.file_field :file %><br>
        <%= u.submit "Upload" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**uploads.js.coffee**

```
$(document).ready () ->
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

$("#new_upload").dropzone({
    maxFilesize: 25,
    paramName: "upload[file]",
    addRemoveLinks: true
});
```

**uploads_controller.rb**

```
class UploadsController < ApplicationController

def new
    @upload = Upload.new
end

def create
  @upload = Upload.create(upload_params)
  if @upload.save
     render json: { message: "success" }, :status => 200
  else
     render json: { error: @upload.errors.full_messages.join(',')}, :status => 400
  end       
end

def destroy
  @upload = Upload.find(params[:id])
  if @upload.destroy    
    render json: { message: "Archivo eliminado." }
  else
    render json: { message: @upload.errors.full_messages.join(',') }
  end
end

private

def upload_params
    user = current_user.id
    params.require(:upload).permit(:file,:user)
end

end
```

You could also notice that in the **_new.html.erb** file I'm redefining the `@upload` class variable, that was already defined in the controller. If I remove it the **new** action won't work. What's the problem there?

Please ask me if you need me to provide more code or details.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `'data-no-turbolink': true` to the link that opens that page. Turbolinks doesn't always play nice with `$(document).ready` so this will call the link without turbo links.

There is also a gem called [jquery-turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) that might make the current version work without `data-no-turbolink`